# The authentication header received from the server.. BASIC - WFC - NET CORE

Tags: wcf, .net-core, service

i working with WCF (connected service) with .NET CORE, and i want call to wfc service and send xml... but when execute service,
  this throw the next exception

"The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="AXIS"'."

when I run the service in the SOAP UI, I assign the basic authorization option and it works perfect ... but in this part I don't know how to set the type of authorization

I also don't have any configuration xml file, just a json called ConnectedService.json

CODE:

```
var endpoint = new TestService.WebTest_Service.EndpointConfiguration();
var service = new TestService.WebTest_Service(endpoint);

string strXml = _getXml();
TestService.XML xml = new TestService.XML();
xml.document = strXml;

service.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
service.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";

var result = service.invokeAsync(xml); // => THROW ERROR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure the account name and password are correct, you also can use the domain/user.

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = @"domain\username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password  = "password";
```

Secondly, please check the automatically generated service endpoint. It should be located in the `Reference.cs`. The parameter in the constructor is an `enum`, which indicates which endpoint should be used.

```
ServiceReference1.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference1.Service1Client(ServiceReference1.Service1Client.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpBinding_IService1);
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "administrator";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "abcd1234!";
```

At last, we could also manually add Basic Http header in the soap request.

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";

using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(client.InnerChannel))
{
   HttpRequestMessageProperty httpRequestProperty = new HttpRequestMessageProperty();
   httpRequestProperty.Headers[System.Net.HttpRequestHeader.Authorization] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName + ":" + client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password));
   OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties[HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name] = httpRequestProperty;
                   
   // below is a sample call
   int response = client.addNumbers(1, 2);
   Console.WriteLine(response);
   Console.ReadLine();                    
}
```

Feel free to let me know if the problem still exists.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding result = null!;
result = new System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding();
result.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
result.ReaderQuotas = System.Xml.XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas.Max;
result.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
result.AllowCookies = true;
result.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
result.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
result.Security.Transport.ProxyCredentialType = System.ServiceModel.HttpProxyCredentialType.None;
XXXXSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new XXXXSoapClient.EndpointConfiguration();

XX.XXXXSoapClient myobj= new XX.XXXXSSoapClient(endpointConfiguration);
myobj.Endpoint.Binding = result;
.`enter code here`
.
.
 /****Further you may call web service method
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: after trying a bunch of different suggested solutions in other posts, this one finally worked for me. thank you. all you need to do after adding the code above is that you have to actually set the `myobj.ClientCredentials.UserName` object values for `.UserName` and `.Password`